# Highlighting values on an assigned column of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with highlight values on HTML table. I need to highlight only the values on the assigned column instead of the whole table. Any 
 help is appreciated! Thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/raphcLb0/

Here is the JS code I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.selector').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', check); 
    });

    $('.all').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', all); 
    });

    function all(event) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){  
            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","checked");
        } else {
            $("input:checkbox(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","");
        }

        //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");
        check(event);
    }

    function check(event) {
        var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
            return this.name
        }).get()
        $('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function () {
            return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
        }).addClass("highlight")
        if ($(this).is(".selector"))
            $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)
    }

    $( "#Hidden").on( "click", function() {
         $(".selector").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: its working fine. When I check 4. Only "4" boxes are highlighted. Whats issue??

Comment: For example, when I click "4" from Sdv values, I need only the 4s on Sdv column to be highlighted. or if I click "all" for Sdv values, only the all values on sdv column should be highlighted. Now when you click "4" as an example, all the 4s on the table are highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', check); 
});
    $('.all').each(function() {
       $(this).on('click', all); 
    });

function all(event) {

        if($(this).is(':checked')){  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","checked");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","");
    }

    //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");

    check(event);
}

function check(event) {
    var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
        return this.name
    }).get()
    $('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function () {
        return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0 &&
              $('#form' + ($(this).index() + 1)).find('[name="'+$(this).text()+'"]').is(":checked")
    }).addClass("highlight")
    if ($(this).is(".selector"))
        $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)

}


 $( "#Hidden").on( "click", function() {
        $(".selector").toggle();
    });



});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/raphcLb0/19/)

What I did is correct the id's of the forms and add the following line:

`$('#form' + ($(this).index() + 1)).find('[name="'+$(this).text()+'"]').is(":checked")`

What this does is select the form with the id containing the index of the current `td` element relative to its `tr` parent. Then it finds the checkbox with the correct name value matching the `td`'s text content in that form and checks if it's checked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Jacques Marais. This is what I needed.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.